# cocos2d - textures are not found on the device

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Here's my code with I use to create sprite thanks to cocos2d.

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"bambusowy.plist"];
  CCSpriteSheet *teksturySheet = [CCSpriteSheet spriteSheetWithFile:@"bambusowy.png"];
  [self addChild:teksturySheet];
  
  
    
   NSString * stttt = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: tex_dane[mapa1[i][0]].c_str()];
   

   CCSprite *teksturka = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:stttt];
```

This code works fine on the Simulator, but it crash on the device.
Here are the logs:

> Tue Aug 10 15:36:39 unknown menu
> panda[1271] : *** Assertion
> failure in -[CCSprite
> initWithTexture:rect:],
> /Users/.... libs/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:183
>
> Tue unknown menu
> panda[1271] : *** Terminating
> app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
> reason: 'Invalid texture for sprite'

I guess the problem is that it cant select texture from an atlas...

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to find an answer to this question as well.  It seems any texture larger than 1024 x 1024 will crash on iPhone 3Gs, could that be the case for you as well?  I've reduced the size of my textures and they run OK now.